# Access to path .... is denied when deleting file

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream

I'm stuck with an issue for a while, when trying to delete one file from a specific folder using `File.Delete()`, there this error `Access to the path <path to the file> is denied` 
however it used to work fine before and the file is not read only and I have full permission.

This is for the file creation:

```
string tempIeDriverServerFile = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "IEDriverServer.exe");

using (FileStream file = new FileStream(tempIeDriverServerFile, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
{
    byte[] bytes = Resources.IEDriverServer;

    file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

After using it, I must delete it with this code

```
if ((File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\IEDriverServer.exe")))
{
    File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\IEDriverServer.exe");
}
```

Comment: Check if the file is properly closed or some other thread or process has accessed it.

Comment: This code is perfectly fine to me.

Comment: One point I noted is that you use `Path.Combine` for making the path for file creation, but string concatenation for checking existence and deletion. Have you verified that they're producing the same results? Generally `Path.Combine` is to be preferred, especially as it avoids you having to muck about with backslashes in strings (and is safe across platforms, if you're needing to run on Mono).

Comment: at least 99% of the time you see this error its your own code locking the file. Especially in your case where you're writing to it in the first place.

Comment: Also, depending on the path your application is located, it may not have access to delete anything in there.
Same applies for the user who executes it.

Comment: Are you using any FileOpenDialog? I remember if you use Windows file select dialog, that changes the CurrentDirectory environment variable. Try to print the Path of file and check it is the expected location.

Comment: Yeah, what @growwithwpf said. The most likely culprit is your handle is not released. When you say "used to work fine before", what has changed since then? Can you manually verify/kill the process that uses the file (or is it still running if it is an exe)?

Comment: Access to the path is denied means you don't have sufficient permissions. Where is the file located? Have you tried running your app as administrator?

Comment: I do have full permissions, I guess it's something that another thread is using it or maybe the file is not closed.
how to check that ?

Comment: Use unlocker (http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to check which process is holding handle to the file

Comment: You write an exe file, i think that you execute the file. Are you shure that the exe is terminated when you try to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the file is being used; in case of an exe file it usually means the process is running. You can see why a file is locked by using one of file unlocker programs, like [Unlocker](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/unlocker.html) or [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/)